# Link to a specific (current) revision on GitHub

Tags: git, github

Here is a sample project on github: http://github.com/ripper234/Test-grails-project

I would like to capture the latest revision, and send a link to it to someone, so that even if the project changes later he will see the specific revision I was talking about. I guess forking could do that, but it's overkill.

How do I do that?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821235/how-to-link-to-specific-line-number-on-github

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To access a single file or directory:

- While browsing directories: Click on the "latest commit <refid>" link at the top of the file list, and then "Browse code" in the blue area near the top.
- While viewing a file: Click on "History" and then on the "<>" button next to the refid to get a link.

Answer (score 49):

Just press `y` and the URL will change automatically to reflect the current version.

[Source](https://help.github.com/articles/getting-permanent-links-to-files/#press-y-to-permalink-to-a-file-in-a-specific-commit)

Comment: My mind is absolutely blown! Thank you!

Comment: Will this only affect what you see on the webpage or will it also affect what you download, for example if you clone the repository or choose "Download ZIP"?

Answer (score 7):

To show the state of the project at a specific commit:

`https://github.com/`**<user>**`/`**<project>**`/tree/`**<commit-hash>**

For example:

- https://github.com/toraritte/software-licensing-a-primer/tree/9f122e02949f966445ad37b1541b70114c9dd602
- or with shortened hash from `git log` 
   https://github.com/toraritte/software-licensing-a-primer/tree/9f122e0

---

The easiest way without editing the URL is:

> 1. Choose a commit (either the latest or from the list of commits)

[image]

> 2. Select "Browse files"

[image]

Answer (score 5):

let's say you would like that the someone you send this link

- http://github.com/ripper234/Test-grails-project/commit/c3110a562339a20eaa4c99e25d2e92538bd6c23d

has to work on the resulting code of this commit.

he would do this:

- git clone git://github.com/ripper234/Test-grails-project.git
- cd Test-grails-project
- git checkout c3110a562339a20eaa4c99e
- git branch c3110a562339a20eaa4c99e

now the user has a branch with the code of the mentioned commit.

does this answer your question? -> not sure if I understood it right...

Answer (score 2):

as mentioned in other answer - for latest commit `y` is the shortcut

---

for any commit

click on `commits`

[image]

and then click on `code` icon ([octicon-code](https://octicons.github.com/icon/code/))

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The URL format is as follows:
https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO/blob/COMMITID/FILENAME

Replace the capitalised elements with details for your case