# How to link to a specific line number on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I know I can link to a specific line number on a file on a GitHub repository (I'm sure I've seen this before)...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 774, accepted):

Don't just link to the line numbers! Be sure to use the [canonical URL](https://help.github.com/en/articles/getting-permanent-links-to-files) too. Otherwise when that file is updated, you'll have a URL that points to the wrong lines!

**How to make a permanent link to the right lines:**

Click on the line number you want (like line 18), and the URL in your browser will get a `#L18` tacked onto the end. You literally click on the `18` at the left side, not the line of code. Looks like this:

[image: line 18 selected]

And now your browser's URL looks like this:

```
https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/README.md?plain=1#L18
```

If you want multiple lines selected, simply hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and click a second line number, like line 20. Looks like this:

[image]

And now your browser's URL looks like this:

```
https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/README.md?plain=1#L18-L20
```

**Here's the important part:**

Now get the canonical URL for that particular commit by pressing the <kbd>Y</kbd> key. The URL in your browser will change to become something like this:

```
https://github.com/git/git/blob/5bdb7a78adf2a2656a1915e6fa656aecb45c1fc3/README#L18-L20
```

That link contains the actual [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hash for that particular commit, rather than the current version of the file on `master`. That means that this link will work forever and not point to lines 18-20 of whatever future version of that file might contain.

Now bask in the glow of your new permanent link. ;-)

After this answer was originally written, *watashiSHUN* pointed out that GitHub has now made it easier to get the permanent link. A `...` menu is provided on the left after you select one or more lines, like this:

[image: GitHub permalink menu]

Please see [watashiSHUN's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45578779/3982562) too.

Note that GitHub does not show line numbers for some "renderable" files, like Markdown files. Adding `?plain=1` to the url will show the source file with line numbers, e.g. `https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/README.md?plain=1`.

Comment: Nice addition!  Thanks for chiming in (even if it is a year later)!

Comment: I only chimed in because the accepted answer will produce an incorrect link when the code changes. Yikes!

Comment: The y key does nothing for me. Has this been changed? Trying from Google Chrome Dev Channel.

Comment: It still works... Docs still say to use `y` key too... https://help.github.com/articles/getting-permanent-links-to-files/

Comment: that shift+click the second line for a block is a good one! I was manually editing the URL to add the second line :). follow up question though, what if I wanted lines 2, 4, and from 17-22 highlighted? Is that possible or can I only highlight one block at a time?

Comment: @tr3buchet I just pinged github support -- it's not possible at the moment. They said they will consider the feature, but no promises. I offered that the format be something like `L18-L20,L29`, and that a person could `CTRL`-click to add non-consecutive lines. I think your idea is a great suggestion and would be very useful.

Comment: @broc.seib thanks for checking it out! I hope they do it at some point because using multiple links to communicate each section in the same gist is a bit painful.. I was thinking about adding it to https://github.com/tr3buchet/gister but i think it's a bit out of scope

Comment: This does not work for me; they `y`key does nothing. The key is also not listed in the "Keyboad Shortcut" list which is called forth by pressing `?`. A workaround would be to go to the desired commit on the "Commits" screen and selecting "Browse files" of that particular commit, then link from there.

Comment: @Svaberg what you see on github when you press `?` is context sensitive. While viewing a file (not a directory), you'll discover that `?` indeed lists `y` as an option, and does actually work. ;-)

Comment: **Now get the canonical url for that particular commit by pressing the y key.** <---- This line compelled  me to upvote this answer.

Comment: I can see that using such a link in an issue will showup the lines as a code snippet when used in a discussion (issue, PR), but it doesn't work in README.md not in wikis. (related: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-permanent-link-to-a-code-snippet/)

Comment: What if `README` is `README.md`?

Comment: Is it possible to link to specific lines of a pull request in the pull request message itself?

Comment: How would this be done in Gists with multiple files? i.e. How would one highlight lines 12-15 of _SomeFragment.kt_ in [AssistedInjectModule.kt](https://gist.github.com/AdamSHurwitz/964a37c60161d74b80cb8a1e520f2bef)?

Comment: @AdamHurwitz look like it is the same approach -- SHIFT-click the line numbers, and the URL in your browser window will be updated, which you can copy/paste. Alas, there is no "Copy Permalink" UI menu. [Lines 12-15 in SomeFragment.kt](https://gist.github.com/AdamSHurwitz/964a37c60161d74b80cb8a1e520f2bef#file-somefragment-kt-L12-L15)

Comment: Is it possible to render a code snippet from a link using the GitHub API?

Comment: The `y` key also updates to the canonical link in GitLab. Awesome!

Comment: Instead of adding a bunch of updates to the answer, why not just replace it with the current working solution?

Comment: It's very important to note that this only works for links to files on the same repo you made the comment on. I'm not sure why it's not documented *ANYWHERE*.

Answer (score 89):

[*broc.seib* has a sophisticated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31282559/3982562), but I just want to point out that instead of pressing <kbd>Y</kbd> to get the permanent link, GitHub now has a very simple UI that helps you to achieve it.

1. Select a line by clicking on the line number or select multiple lines by downholding <kbd>Shift</kbd> (the same as how you select multiple folders in [File Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer)):

   [image]
2. On the right hand corner of the first line you selected, expand `...` and  click *copy permalink*

   [image]
3. That's it. A link with the selected lines and a commit hash is copied to your clipboard:

   `https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c82b7f332aff606af6c9c163da75f1e86514125e/Doc/Makefile#L1-L4`

Comment: This ... does not show up in commit diffs, unfortunately.

Answer (score 34):

See:

[image: A permalink to a code snippet is pasted into a pull request comment field]

You can you use permalinks to include code snippets in issues, PRs, etc.

**References:**

*[Creating a permanent link to a code snippet](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-permanent-link-to-a-code-snippet)*

Comment: Pretty nice gif!

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic, but what tool do you use to make it?

Comment: @GiovanniBenussi It is from GitHub. See the link.

Comment: I mean for the gif :-P hahaha

Comment: @GiovanniBenussi I don't know what reversiblean used but occasionally I make gifs like this using a nice tool called "screentogif",you should try it out https://github.com/NickeManarin/ScreenToGif

Answer (score 23):

Click the line number, and then copy and paste the link from the address bar. To select a range, click the number, and then shift click the later number.

Alternatively, the links are a relatively simple format, just append `#L<number>` to the end for that specific line number, using the link to the file. Here's a link to the third line of the `git` repository's `README`:

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/README#L3

[image: Screenshot with highlighted line and the modified address line]

Comment: Don't forget that if the file changes, this URL will still point to line 3, which could contain new code, and may not be what you wanted! I've offered another solution that yields a permanent link. Hint: just press `y`. ;-)

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 7):

Many editors (but also see the *Commands* section below) support linking to a file's line number or range on GitHub or Bitbucket (or others). Here's a short list:

### [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor))

[Open on GitHub](https://github.com/atom/open-on-github)

### [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs)

[git-link](https://github.com/sshaw/git-link)

### [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text)

[GitLink](https://github.com/rscherf/GitLink)

### [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29)

[gitlink-vim](https://github.com/iautom8things/gitlink-vim)

---

### Commands

- [git-link](https://github.com/gvalkov/git-link) - Git subcommand for getting a repository browser link to a Git object
- [ghwd](https://github.com/github-modules/ghwd) - Open the GitHub URL that matches your shell's current branch and working directory

Answer (score 3):

Related to how to link to the *README.md* file of a GitHub repository to a specific line number of code

You have three cases:

1. We can *link to* (custom **commit**)

   But *Link* will *always* link
   to an old file version, which will *not* contain new updates in the
   master branch for example. Example:

   ```
   https://github.com/username/projectname/blob/b8d94367354011a0470f1b73c8f135f095e28dd4/file.txt#L10
   ```
2. We can *link to* (custom **branch**) like (master-branch).
   But the link will *always* link to the latest file version which will contain new
   updates. Due to new updates, the link may point to an invalid business line number.
   Example:

   ```
   https://github.com/username/projectname/blob/master/file.txt#L10
   ```
3. GitHub can *not* make an *auto*-link to any file either to (custom
   commit) nor (master-branch).
   Because of following business issues:

   - ***line*** business meaning, to link to it in the new file
   - ***length of target highlighted code*** which can be changed

Comment: It's good that someone pointed this out. Wish it was easy to find a compromise, like binding to line and forward tracking where it's currently in the new version. OR at least have link that points to wherever the certain substring is needed.

Answer (score 1):

For a line in a pull request.

```
https://github.com/foo/bar/pull/90/files#diff-ce6bf647d5a531e54ef0502c7fe799deR27
```

```
https://github.com/foo/bar/pull/
90 <- PR number
/files#diff-
ce6bf647d5a531e54ef0502c7fe799de <- MD5 has of file name from repo root
R <- Which side of the diff to reference (merge-base or head). Can be L or R.
27 <- Line number
```

This will take you to a line as long as L and R are correct. I am not sure if there is a way to visit L *OR* R. I.e If the PR adds a line you must use `R`. If it removes a line you must use `L`.

From: [Generate line pointer URL into Github Pull Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46383301/generate-line-pointer-url-into-github-pull-request)

Answer (score 1):

#### Linking to a line number on a GitHub wiki page

I was having some trouble finding how to link to a specific location on a GitHub wiki page and ended up finding this out.  ***This might be common knowledge***, but I didn't know this and someone else might find it useful.

When browsing a wiki file you can put your mouse over a specific header text and a link icon will appear.  Clicking this link icon, your browser navigation URL will be updated (example: `https://github.com/user/repository/wiki/Test#title-1`).  This would be the link to that specific location in the wiki file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a preview rendering of a **Markdown code snippet**, after copying the link as mentioned in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821235/how-to-link-to-specific-line-number-on-github#45578779), remove the `?plain=1` parameter from the link.

For example, the following will show a plain text link:

```
github.com/<organization>/<repository>/blob/<branch_name>/README.md?plain=1#L14
```

After removing the `?plain=1` parameter, it will show the preview of the code:

```
github.com/<organization>/<repository>/blob/<branch_name>/README.md#L14
```

[image: A link to a Markdown with preview]

See [GitHub documentation: Creating a permanent link to a code snippet](https://docs.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/creating-a-permanent-link-to-a-code-snippet) for more information.

Comment: Linking to rendered markdown file (preview) doesn't work for me. It shows the file but does not scroll to the selected line.
Linking to raw file (plain=1) works.
Any thoughts?

Comment: @grubykarol since markdown is rendered on github.com, is not possible to link to a line in rendered state, but if you, or the people you want to share the link with, use chrome there is an alternative: use the [copy link to highlight](https://blog.google/products/chrome/more-helpful-chrome-throughout-your-workday/) feature on the markdown file in rendered state over the selected text