# How to link to specific line number on git?

Tags: git

I searched everywhere, only to find a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821235/how-to-link-to-specific-line-number-on-github) but about GitHub rather than Git on Stack Overflow.

I need a link locally referring to a line in a branch in a file and in a repository. I know I can do it by using a global mark, for instance in Vim, but can I skin a cat in a Git way?  I only know a little about the plumbing commands of Git. Maybe in `repository/branch/file/line` form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `git show` and output it to vim along with a specific line number like the following:

```
git show branch_name:your_file | vim - +45
```

or use a specific hash:

```
git show b4524bcd:your_file | vim - +45
```

Comment: If you only want to print a specific line number you can pipe it to `sed -n 45p` instead of vim.

Comment: you can specify a directory before the `show` part: `git --git-dir=my_folder/.git show ...`. Just keep in mind you'll have to target `.git` directory within your project.