# How to quote lines from source in github markup

Tags: github

I have seen this post on [How to link to specific line number on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821235/how-to-link-to-specific-line-number-on-github) which tells you how to create a permalink to lines of source code on github. That's great!

My question is, how can you quote lines of code in a Stackoverflow post such that you see the code & the line numbers - just as you would if you view the source code directly?

The only way I currently know to quote code is literally copying & pasting it into the post; but then you need to include the permalink or quote line numbers as well so that the people reading your post know where in the source file to look. It would be so much easier if they could just see the code & link number in the post.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to add in the line number yourself but the GitHub flavor markdown for blockquotes and code are documented [here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#code-and-syntax-highlighting).