# Vim YouCompleteMe adds [ID] after every suggestion

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

I installed YCM and it works fine, but every word suggestion is followed by `[ID]` (see below).

[image]

What does `[ID]` mean, how can it be used and the main question is - Is it possible to get rid of `[ID]`? if yes - then how?

By the way, I'm using Vim on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Read the plugin's documentation and/or use the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution if anyone needs. 
In file `identifier_completer.py` which is located in
`~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycmd/completers/all/`
in line 66
`'extra_menu_info='[ID]' )`
`'[ID]'` can be replaced by empty string `''`. that works.

Comment: The `identifier_completer.py` you're referring to is [that one](https://github.com/Valloric/ycmd/blob/b74add9c32f6edd71e165a7151fac12cf8a9a32c/ycmd/completers/all/identifier_completer.py#L66). This is a [permanent link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31282559/1121933) (quoted, for further reference).

Answer (score 0):

`ID` shows that it is a variable.

You will also get `F` for functions, and many more like that.