# Generate line pointer URL into Github Pull Request

Tags: git, github, github-api, pull-request

I am trying to auto-generate a URL that can point to a line number into the GitHub Pull request's file diff view.

Basically, given the URL `https://github.com/weppos/whois/pull/90/files` I'd like to generate URL like https://github.com/weppos/whois/pull/90/files#diff-ce6bf647d5a531e54ef0502c7fe799deR27 that can point to the line 27 of file in the GitHub pull request. Looking at the URL, seems like it's combination of

https://github.com/weppos/whois/pull/90/ 
+
files/#diff-
+
ce6bf647d5a531e54ef0502c7fe799de
+
R27

I am not sure how to retrieve number ce6bf647d5a531e54ef0502c7fe799de given everything else is known. It'd be great if someone can provide some pointers. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if GitHub provides this endpoint. It might be good to mail this question to GitHub support. they are very responsive.

Comment: @vishrut if my answer below worked for you, please mark it as the best answer http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png if not feel free to comment and I can help you debug this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Github API docs (found [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests-files)) suggest the following API endpoint:

```
GET /repos/weppos/whois/pulls/90/files
```

which would result in something similar to the following:

```
[
    {
        "blob_url": "https://github.com/weppos/whois/blob/aa16f66c9dca556b7db131b68b0b99d435bc43d8/lib/whois/errors.rb", 
        "filename": "lib/whois/errors.rb", 
        "sha": "beec7aad75671e40a21532044c0e4dc23f7f226a", 
        "status": "modified",
        ...
    }, 
    ...
]
```

The value you are looking for here is the **MD5** hash of filename `lib/whois/errors.rb` which is `ce6bf647d5a531e54ef0502c7fe799de`.

Comment: you can use https://www.md5hashgenerator.com/ to generate an md5 online or use your programming language of choice.

Comment: I believe this answer might be outdated. Just tried the same in another PR. But the filename is "README.md" on root directory.. not sure if it is different there

Comment: Github now uses the SHA256 of the filename.

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted here by @mostafazh is outdated.

Nowadays github moved to using sha256, but the approach is still the same.

You can check this by pasting the a hash on [hashanalyzer](https://www.tunnelsup.com/hash-analyzer/)