# Github urls for file change diffs

Tags: github, danger

I am trying to get hyperlinks to the file diff version of a file shown in the Files tab in github in a PR:

[image]

When I click on the file name the url changes from:

https://github.com/x/pull/4985/files

to:

https://github.com/x/pull/4985/files#diff-0155c51c06995041621random6789767nne2e22d8815151e22b9d4c68b8a80

How is github generating this part:
#diff-0155c51c06995041621random6789767nne2e22d8815151e22b9d4c68b8a80 - is it possible to calculate this in code via some sha algorithm and create this hyperlink synthetically ?

The reason for doing this, is I want to generate this url to be able to go to this url in a dangerjs check that im writing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate line pointer URL into Github Pull Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46383301/generate-line-pointer-url-into-github-pull-request)

Comment: Yes @XinheWang - this is a great resource thanks for the information