# How to Markdown preview and jump to line number

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to jump to a line number with a markdown link in VSCode?

for example

```
| [/path/to/MyFile.ts](/path/to/MyFile.ts<---line-number) Jump to MyFile.ts line 123
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like was just fixed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69824214/836330.  Not sure if was broken sometime after the below answers???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appeared to be a bug is vscode. Which is fixed now. Thanks everyone for the answer.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, use `L123` as the link fragment. For example:

```
[/path/to/MyFile.ts](/path/to/MyFile.ts#L123)

[MyRelativeFile.ts](MyRelativeFile.ts#L123)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is an Anchor link.

https://gist.github.com/asabaylus/3071099

Comment: I tried adding #<number> at the end of the url but it does not work unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821235/how-to-link-to-specific-line-number-on-github

Comment: If I followed correctly in that link, you'll see that if you go to your target file (MyFile.ts) and highlight the line you want it should update your URL. However when I tested this locally you actually have to select the number of the line you want.  So within github select that line by clicking the number.  If you 'Copy Permalink" it will give you what you want to link to