# How can I link from a markdown document in VSCode into another file in an editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, vscode-extensions

In working on a VSCode extension that runs an analysis on solidity code and creates a markdown report for that I came across this the report contains source code filenames, and a range of text.

How can I have that link to places in the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was just fixed: [Linking to file with line number from markdown only works for .md files](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125320)
.

So now this works:

`[b.ts](b.ts#L60)`