# How to permanently link to a line in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was wondering if it is possible to create a permanent link to a line in the same file in visual studio code. I saw that in GitHub you can do this ([How to link to specific line number on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821235/how-to-link-to-specific-line-number-on-github)). Is it possible to do the same in visual studio code?

Comment: You might use the extension [Bookmarks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.Bookmarks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the extension I made [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links) (better name would be Related Links) you can create a file that contains the filename and `line:character_pos` that you want to jump to.

If you open this file and lock the `HTML Related Links` View in the explorer to this file you have these links always available and they will update when you edit the file with links.

If you have a `.txt` file with content like:

```
src/module1/fileA.js@123
src/module3/fileB.js@54
```

You can use the following setting:

```
"html-related-links.include": {
    "plaintext": [
      {
        "find": "([\\w.]+)@(\\d+)",
        "filePath": "/$1",
        "lineNr": "$2"
      }
    ]
  }
```

At the moment the bookmarking is done manually by editing the `.txt` file.

I can have a look if can add a context menu entry to the editor.

Comment: you should disclose your affiliation. [/help/promotion](/help/promotion).