# vs code linked comments

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to link comments from one file to another

this is the folder structure that i have.
what I usually do is along with my backend code i have a rest client (its a VSCode extension to call http requests from inside vs code)

```
-->backend code folder
  -->adminroute.js  
  -->userroute.js
-->http test folder
  -->admin.http
  -->user.http
```

```
//---- example backend file -----/
// HTTP POST {{url}}/_/admin/api/auth/login
routerAdd("POST", "_/admin/api/auth/login", async (c) => {
    try {
        const data = $apis.requestInfo(c);
        const authRecord = data.authRecord;
        return c.json(200, authRecord)
    } catch (error){
        return c.html(401, {message: "you are not logged in"})
    }
}, $apis.requireRecordAuth())
```

```
//---example http test file ------/
### // HTTP POST {{url}}/_/admin/api/auth/login
*sendrequest*
POST {{url}}/_/admin/api/auth/login
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "identity": "gokul@gseven.in",
    "password": "12345678"
}
```

what i am looking for is a way to create a link between the comments "// HTTP POST {{url}}/_/admin/api/auth/login" on both the file , so that when i click on one of them i get transported to the other place the comment is located. (purely for navigation so after i write a api i click on it comment and quickly test the api and then go back to the code page)

is there a extension that does something similar
or maybe a way to do something

looked for a couple of extensions but couldn't find something that worked

Comment: potential dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/64284060/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/70224273/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/76739915/11107541

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension I made: [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links) v1.2.0

Using the following setting (`.http` files are designated as `plaintext`, change if needed) you can Ctrl+Click on the comments to jump between the code and the test:

```json
  "html-related-links.include": {
    "javascript": [
      { "find": "(// HTTP (?:GET|POST) \\{\\{url\\}\\}([\\w/]+))",
        "filePath": "../httptest/${fileBasenameNoExtension#find=route$#replace=#}.http",
        "label": "$1",
        "lineSearch": "$1"
      }
    ],
    "plaintext": [
      { "find": "(// HTTP (?:GET|POST) \\{\\{url\\}\\}([\\w/]+))",
        "filePath": "../backend/${fileBasenameNoExtension}route.js",
        "label": "$1",
        "lineSearch": "$1"
      }
    ]
  }
```

---

P.S. **Never** use spaces in file and directory names